# How to convert nvarchar to datetime without additional select return in query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I've got sql query:

```
declare @x nvarchar(50) = '2011-11-11'
select convert(datetime, @x)

SELECT * FROM T
    WHERE dt > @x
```

but unfortunately it returns two results when I need only single one, so how can I do the same avoiding nvarchar to datetime convert results in query results?

Comment: Why not just do `DECLARE @x AS datetime = '20111101'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION:

```
declare @x nvarchar(50)
SET @x = '2006-11-11'

SELECT dt FROM T WHERE dt >  convert(datetime, @x)
```

**Regards

Ali Muhammad**

Comment: Note that this will give different results depending on server setup or login settings.